# How do I convert this project to use nibs instead of programmatically creating views?

Tags: ios, animation, nib

I would like to have [this example project](http://www.modejong.com/iPhone/PNGAnimatorDemo.zip) use a nib for all the views instead of creating views programmatically.

Can someone walk me through the steps required to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project is already using a xib for the main view. If you want to use a xib for the `ImageAnimatorViewController` you should replace this:

```
+ (ImageAnimatorViewController*) imageAnimatorViewController
{
  return [[[ImageAnimatorViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

with this:

```
+ (ImageAnimatorViewController*) imageAnimatorViewController
{
  return [[[ImageAnimatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
```

then create the xib (new file -> user interface -> view). Set the File's Owner of the view to ImageAnimatorViewController and hook up the view outlet to File's Owner -> view.

Beyond that you'll presumably want to remove any programmatic layout code and replace with UI objects that you designate as IBOutlet in the ImageAnimatorViewController.h

Comment: incidentally, thanks for posting this - I used to work with Mo long ago and now I know what he's up to these days.

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks so much for the answer. One question: How do I set the nib's owner?

Comment: the problem is when I try to grab the "referencing outlet" and connect it to File's Owner nothing pops up.

Comment: In Xcode 4 you would click on the xib in the project explorer, then click on the File's Owner Object in "Placeholders" Then, with the right panel expanded you would choose the tab with the file information and select the relevant class from the dropdown at the top.

Comment: thanks again... do I need to change anything in ImageAnimatorViewController.h?